# What to do if a player gets the "Donjon" card from the Deck of Many Things?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

In DnD 5e, there is an item called the [Deck of Many Things](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/deck-of-many-things).

There are many possible cards that can be drawn from the deck. For example, one might draw the "Donjon" card, which has the following effect:

> **Donjon.** You disappear and become entombed in a state of suspended animation in an extradimensional sphere. Everything you were wearing and carrying stays behind in the space you occupied when you disappeared. You remain imprisoned until you are found and removed from the sphere. You can't be located by any divination magic, but a wish spell can reveal the location of your prison. You draw no more cards.

As a player, I don't see how it would be fair for something like that to happen. Could the effects be nerfed or something so it's on the same plane of existence?

I just want to know what a GM would do if a player pulls the Donjon card; should they stick to the rules or nerf it a bit?

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you're asking here. Are you asking whether the Deck of Many Things is fair? Whether it's balanced? Whether DMs are allowed to change the rules? Whether the DM *should* change the rules in this case?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a very broad question with a lot of open ends, but I'll give it my best shot.

Firstly, the Deck of Many Things is a potential campaign killer. If you're expecting this item to appear in your campaign, you should expect that it will be derailed or even potentially ended due to the results.

If you're concerned about the deck causing too much irreversible damage (à la the Donjon card), I recommend either avoiding it entirely or asking your DM very nicely to consider removing cards that can/will cause irreparable harm.

This all comes down to the kind of game that you are playing though, if you're in a chaotic campaign with a fast-and-loose playstyle; the Deck might not be a huge issue. If you're in a slower and more serious campaign with long running arcs and plot development, then getting teleported to another dimension is probably an issue.

Now for the classic line; ***talk to your DM.*** If you're concerned about your character blinking out of existence, this is something that you're DM should be aware of so that it doesn't accidentally happen.

Comment: No campaign I have ever played in has survived a DoMT... Someone inevitably takes one too many cards.

Comment: Yeah, the DoMT is kind of designed to "break" a campaign.

Comment: Jesus, We're all level 3! maybe i shouldn't pull from it then if theres a chance of getting "The Skull"

Comment: @Eimsmaul that is definitely the best way to avoid derailing a campaign.

Comment: @Eimsmaul At level 3 you should definitely not have that deck. It's more of a level 17+ thing, and even then as others have said it's a campaign-ender/derailer